# Unable to load custom files using composer

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I have a folder name `classes` in the root directory at same level where the `vendor` directory is.

in the `classes` folder i have files like

1. billing.php
2. connection.php
3. producer.php

All of these classes have a names space for example

```
// connection.php
namespace Blah;
class Connection {}

// billing.php
namespace Blah;
class Billing{}
```

I have an index.php file where i want these classes available without using `require` or `include`. Below is the `composer.json` file i am using.

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^2.6",
        "zeuxisoo/slim-whoops": "0.3.0",
        "videlalvaro/php-amqplib": "v2.1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Blah\\": "classes/"
        }
    }
}
```

I run `composer dump-autload` as well but i am unable to get these classes loaded. On index.php i am getting

```
Class 'Blah\Connection' not found
```

Here is my index.php code:

```
<?php
// index.php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Blah\Connection;

$connection = Connection::getInstance();
```

I am fairly new in composer and namespacing stuff. Need guidance of what i am doing wrong here. Thanks

Comment: I've just tried your code and found it to be working fine. Have you ran composer install? Otherwise can you post your full composer.json file? Also where exactly is your index file? Is it in the root dir?

Comment: i ran composer dump-autoload because composer install i have ran already @PaulSaunders

Comment: @PaulSaunders i updated the composer.json part in my question. That is full content of my composer.json. index.php file is at same level where composer.json file is

Comment: Yer it looks fine to me, I'm getting an error because I haven't added the getInstance function (which I'd expect)

Comment: Check the namespace on the Connection file, does it match the one in composer exactly? Can you update your answer and copy the Technomessages namespaces in to the classes?

Comment: @PaulSaunders sorry i replaced it with Blah.

Comment: Actually, can you rename the file to Connection (with an uppercase C)

Comment: @PaulSaunders does file names make any effect? All my file names are small case

Comment: Yes thats the issue, I recreated on mine

Comment: It works. Can you please post it as answer. Also, i have to rename all PHP Builtin classes with a \ to avoid collision. Is there any better way for this that i don't have to put a \ before every PHP class

Comment: I've posted an answer. I'm afraid I don't know about that, I tend to always use the \. It'll be helpful If ever I implement my own case called DateTime haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the file names are case sensitive. If you rename your file Connection.php (rather than connection.php) it'll solve your issue